# Make the browser reload when user adds hash to to URL

Tags: javascript, html, http

So let's say you have a URL like this: http://yoursite.com/#stackoverflow

If I type a new hash into the address bar, it tries to find that ID on the page. Is there amy way (possibly with javascript?) to detect that browser activity and then force the page to reload at that URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this isn't a particularly good idea. The hash isn't sent to the server precisely because it's *not* supposed to result in fetching a different resource :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    window.location.reload();
};
```

Careful though: some older browsers do not support this event ([see this](http://caniuse.com/hashchange)), so you'll need a polyfill for those.

Here's an example plus a polling technique for older browsers:

```
if ('onhashchange' in window) {
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        window.location.reload();
    };
} else {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    setInterval(function() {
       if (window.location.hash !== hash) {
           window.location.reload();
       }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: What's the browser support for this like?

Answer (score 0):

On newer browsers, you can use the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange). Support for it is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange), actually. On older browsers, you have to poll the [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) (e.g., with `setInterval` or `setTimeout`).

Comment: With the polling, how do I prevent it from constantly refreshing over and over? Ionly want it to refresh when the URL is changed.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: 1. When you're starting your polling, store the initial hash in a variable. 2. In the polling function, compare the current `location.hash` to the one you've stored. 3. Reload if they're different. :-)

Comment: @JacksonGariety: See link above for browser support for `hashchange`.

Answer (score 0):

Worth a look,

This little plugin provides an abstraction for cross browser support.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: @999's answer is just a more lightweight version of this. Thanks tho!